# What could be the problem in the following code snippet?

Tags: c

The following piece of code was giving a segmentation fault whenever i was trying to pass ./a.out www.yahoo.com at the shell...

```
 main(int c,char *argv[])
 {
     struct hostent *ptr;
     ptr = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
     printf("%s\n", ptr->h_name);
 }
```

Comment: @ThiefMaster: He can name it whatever he likes.

Comment: On a Linux system that builds fine (and runs fine) with gcc 4.5 (after adding #include for  `netdb.h`, `sys/socket.h` and `stdio.h`)

Comment: @DeadMG: True, but `argc`/`argv` are the de-facto standard.

Answer (score 9):

You should check the return value (ptr) if it is NULL (gethostbyname returns NULL on error). When the function returns NULL you can check h_errno to see what exactly happened. See also: http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/gethostbyname/

You should also check the number of command line arguments befor you pass an argument to the gethostbyname function:

```
if(c < 2) {
    /* print an error */
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're passing an argument to the application's command line?

**EDIT**
You must also check that `gethostbyname()` doesn't returns NULL.

Comment: `whenever i was trying to pass ./a.out www.yahoo.com at the shell...`

Answer (score 1):

- Check if two parameters are passed as command line parameters
- Check if `gethostbyname` returned a valid pointer, and report problem as needed

.

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
   struct hostent *ptr;

   /* Check if there is enough argument */
   if (argc != 2)
   {
     printf ("\nusage: %s <host_name>\n", argv[0]);
     exit (1);
   }

   /* fill up hostent structure */
   ptr = gethostbyname(argv[1]);

   /* Check if we have a valid one */
   if (ptr != NULL)
   {
     printf ("\n%s\n", ptr->h_name);
   }
   else
   {
     /* Print the error */
     printf ("\n%s", hstrerror (h_errno));
   }

   printf ("\n");
   return 0;
}
```

This works find here on my system with `gcc file.c -Wall -Wextra` and `./a.out` says

```
usage: ./a.out <host_name>
```

And `./a.out yahoo.com` tells

```
yahoo.com
```

**EDIT1:**
Manuals say ...

> The  gethostbyname*()  and  gethostbyaddr*()  functions  are  obsolete.
>          Applications should use getaddrinfo(3) and getnameinfo(3) instead.